# Mean stack: How to access data from MongoDB aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mean-stack

I have the problem, that my aggregation query does not return any results to my res.json()...
The query looks like that in Node / Express:

```
exports.group_Produkt_by_month = function(req,res) {
        Produkt.aggregate([
            {
                "$unwind":"$DemonstratorWerte"
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": {
                        "DemoID": "$DemonstratorWerte.Demonstrator", "Monat": {"$month":"$Erstellungszeitpunkt"}
                    },
                    "Anzahl":{"$sum":1}
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {"DemoID": "$_id.DemoID", "Monat": "$_id.Monat", "Anzahl":1, "_id":0}
            },
            {
                "$addFields": { 
                    "Monat": { 
                        "$let":  { 
                            "vars": {  
                                "monthsInStrings": [, "Januar", "Februar", "Maerz", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"] 
                            }, 
                            "in": {  
                                "$arrayElemAt": ['$$monthsInStrings','$Monat'] 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        ]).exec(function(err, prod) {
        if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

        else {
            console.log(typeof prod);
            console.log(prod[1])
            console.log(prod);
            res.json(prod);
        }
    }).then((res) => res.json())

    }
```

When I execute the query in mongo shell, the query is correctly executed and returns a list of documents. Now I would like to  give me the documents back as res.json(docs) or similar as an array of result documents in the webbrowser... how can I do that? I heard that one has to use the `.toArray()` method, but I dont know how and where to do that in Node/Express...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,
I found out that it was something with my routes I guess... it didn't find the route because it probably was not distinct enough, so I appended more prefix-links /.../... and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the rest api, then do the query or first go through the docs how to fetch/insert data in node using express, Check the folder/file structure where you have to write code. [check here](https://www.terlici.com/2015/08/13/mysql-node-express.html) You can connect any db.

```
exports.group_Produkt_by_month = function(req,res) {
       Produkt.aggregate([
            {
                "$unwind":"$DemonstratorWerte"
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": {
                        "DemoID": "$DemonstratorWerte.Demonstrator", "Monat": {"$month":"$Erstellungszeitpunkt"}
                    },
                    "Anzahl":{"$sum":1}
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {"DemoID": "$_id.DemoID", "Monat": "$_id.Monat", "Anzahl":1, "_id":0}
            },
            {
                "$addFields": { 
                    "Monat": { 
                        "$let":  { 
                            "vars": {  
                                "monthsInStrings": [, "Januar", "Februar", "Maerz", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"] 
                            }, 
                            "in": {  
                                "$arrayElemAt": ['$$monthsInStrings','$Monat'] 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        ],function(err,result) {
        if(err) res.sendStatus(404);
         res.send(result);
      });
 }
```

Comment: well, I have created the complete REST API, with routes, models, app.js, etc...the thing is, my other routes and api methods with Produkt Schema just work fine, I have another aggregation function some lines above, and it gives me back correct json response documents, just with this function, nothing is getting returned, and I am not even getting an error to console, the problem seems, it is not entering the function somehow, but I dont know why... I did "console.log("Entering function...")" at beginning of my function, but nothing is getting printed to console... any ideas?

Comment: my routes function looks like this: function ProduktRoutes(router) {
    var ProduktController = require('../controllers/ProduktController')
    router.route('/Produkt')
      .get(ProduktController.list_all_Produkt)
      .post(ProduktController.create_an_Produkt)
    router.route('/Produkt/:Produkt_id')
       .get(ProduktController.getProduktbyID)
       .put(ProduktController.updateProdukt)
       .delete(ProduktController.deleteProdukt)
    router.route('/Produkt/Monat')      
      .get(ProduktController.group_Produkt_by_month)
}
module.exports = ProduktRoutes;

Comment: check once you are calling the API  with get  as you mentioned above as a get or goto network tab/POSTMAN  check the api with proper method.